# Copy buffer content verbatim

Tags: copy-paste, overlays

Emacs uses overlays / prettify-symbols-mode / etc which modify how data is displayed to user.

I like to copy visible content as I see it. For example I aligned columns in CSV file with `M-x csv-align-fields` but content is copied as it in file (with commas instead of aligned columns).

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you may be interested in https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OverlaysToText. The problem with overlays is that they are generally not considered a part of a buffer's contents.